How to get the name of the fitted function in R
I built a code that fits different copula types to data and selects the best based on the smallest AIC value. The code is working very well. However, the result is as follows:
Normal copula, dim. d = 3 
Dimension:  3 
Parameters:
  rho.1   = 0.8094
dispstr:  ex 

I can then get the dimension and parameters from the result, but the name of the copula. That is, I need to extract the name of the copual. For example,
    selected_copula@parameters
[1] 0.7833736

I also want to be able to use selected_copula@copula to get the name of the best-fitted copula, but it does not work.
The fitCopula function allows us to extract the name of the copula using @copula which I cannot do with my code.
The full code is as follows:
library(copula)
fit_select_copula <- function(copula_list, data) {
  fit_copula_models <- function(copula_list, data) {
    num_copulas <- length(copula_list)
    copula_results <- vector("list", length = num_copulas)

    for (i in seq_along(copula_list)) {
      copula <- copula_list[[i]]
      fitted_model <- fitCopula(copula,data)

      copula_results[[i]] <- list(
        copula = fitted_model@copula,
        loglik = fitted_model@loglik,
        aic = AIC(fitted_model)
      )
    }

    return(copula_results)
  }

  copula_results <- fit_copula_models(copula_list, data)

  aic_values <- sapply(copula_results, function(x) x$aic)
  lowest_aic_index <- which.min(aic_values)

  selected_copula <- copula_results[[lowest_aic_index]]$copula

  return(selected_copula)
}

# Example usage
data <- rCopula(1000, normalCopula(0.8, dim = 3))  # Replace with your actual data
copula_list <- list(
  frank = frankCopula(6, 3),
  clayton = claytonCopula(2, 3),
  normal = normalCopula(0.7, 3)
)

selected_copula <- fit_select_copula(copula_list, data)


since the copula_list has names, then simply do names(copula_results) <- names(copula_list)

I think if you want to have applied your own names in your initial list; you need to then add sufficient bookkeeping to carry those around in your operations.
library(copula)
fit_select_copula <- function(copula_list, data) {
  fit_copula_models <- function(copula_list, data) {
    num_copulas <- length(copula_list)
    copula_names <- names(copula_list) #  <<< ADDED THIS  <<<<
    copula_results <- vector("list", length = num_copulas)
    
    for (i in seq_along(copula_list)) {
      copula <- copula_list[[i]]
      fitted_model <- fitCopula(copula,data)
      
      copula_results[[i]] <- list(
        copula_name = copula_names[[i]], #  <<< ADDED THIS  <<<<
        copula = fitted_model@copula,
        loglik = fitted_model@loglik,
        aic = AIC(fitted_model)
      )
    }
    
    return(copula_results)
  }
  
  copula_results <- fit_copula_models(copula_list, data)
  aic_values <- sapply(copula_results, function(x) x$aic)
  lowest_aic_index <- which.min(aic_values)
  
 ### ALTERED THIS ####
  selected_copula <- list(name=copula_results[[lowest_aic_index]]$copula_name,
                          content = copula_results[[lowest_aic_index]]$copula)
  
  return(selected_copula)
}

# Example usage
data <- rCopula(1000, normalCopula(0.8, dim = 3))  # Replace with your actual data
copula_list <- list(
  frank = frankCopula(6, 3),
  clayton = claytonCopula(2, 3),
  normal = normalCopula(0.7, 3)
)

selected_copula <- fit_select_copula(copula_list, data)

